# Merge word documents, reset any numbered / lettered lists

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word

I have a desktop app that does work on a Word 2003 template then merges all the created documents into one file.

The app is working, except for the merging.  The merge does not reset any numbered / lettered lists.  I've tried a lot of different things including:

```
selection.Range.ListParagraphs[i].Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate(selection.Range.ListParagraphs[i].Range.ListFormat.ListTemplate, ref continuePrevious, ref missing, ref missing);
```

and even trying to merge each document as a Subdocument

```
document.Application.Selection.EndKey(ref unit, ref missing);
document.Application.Selection.Range.Subdocuments.AddFromFile(ref file, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Comment: How are you merging documents together? Please provide more context.